# How to get JOGL GL2 attribute

Tags: java, swing, opengl, abstract, jogl

I'm making all my gui element with custom method using OpenGL (Button, checkbox...). I want to make those method modulable so they can be used with different API different than OpenGL  (ex:Swing). I'm using the abstract factory pattern to do this.

Here a method than implement an abstract function of my factory:

```
    public void select(GL2 gl, List<Integer> resultat, int index,
        MouseEventEnum event) {
    if(m_actif) {
        switch(event) {
        case CLICK:
            if(error_cle_message != null) {
                MiniLogModifiableData mlog = new MiniLogModifiableData(
                        error_cle_message, 3);
                mlog.envoieMessage(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, in all those method I need the GL2 context to perform the operation. Is there a way to access this GL2 context without having to pass it in argument or any other things i'm doing wrong?

Here is a call in another function:

```
m_listeBoutons.get(i)).select(null, null, -1, MouseEventEnum.CLICKED);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [GLContext.getCurrentGL()](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GLContext.html#getCurrentGL%28%29) to get the GL instance but your method must be called when the OpenGL context is current. Look at [the source code of Ardor3D JOGL renderer](https://github.com/gouessej/Ardor3D/tree/master/ardor3d-jogl) to see how I use it.

Why not using GL2ES2 and GL2ES1 where it is possible so that your code has a chance to work with OpenGL-ES too? Your source code would be easier to read if your variables weren't named in French and without respecting Java code conventions. Finally, [the official JogAmp forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/) is a better place to ask questions about JOGL.